# Default rulerformat

Tags: statusline, set, ruler

I like the default `rulerformat`, but I would like to add to it. However it
seems the default value is hidden. If I try these:

```
set rulerformat
set rulerformat?
```

I just get:

```
rulerformat=
```

Same for `statusline`.

Comment: See [this relevant blog post](https://codeyarns.github.io/tech/2010-11-28-vim-ruler-and-default-ruler-format.html)

Comment: I have answered here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7038

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default format of the ruler option is directly set in the C core of Vim. If you do not like the default, you can customize it using the ['rulerformat'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27rulerformat%27) option and using the [statusline format expressions](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27statusline%27).

By experimenting, it seems the default ruler format (when not customized) is:

```
:set rulerformat=%l,%c%V%=%P
                  │  │ │ │ └ position in the file in percent (or ALL/TOP/BOT)
                  │  │ │ └—— right align the following items
                  │  │ └———— virtual (or screen) column, matters for TAB and multibyte chars
                  │  └—————— cursor column (in bytes)
                  └————————— current line
```